# How to catch events of a class in a class helper?

Tags: class, oop, delphi, helper

I want to create a helper for TCustomQuery, TQuery, TTable and so on... With a LastRecordPosition property, which I will get with OnBeforeScroll setting that property from RecNo.

How do I create that trigger in that helper class to catch the event without interfere in an user's OnBeforePost if he/she needs one?

I use FireDAC or ZeosLib for older versions.

Comment: Either way, I'm assuming you need to catch and override such events. Usually classes have a procedure you can override which is called just before the actual event is fired, and those procedures usually have the same name as the event name without the `On` prefix, or sometimes instead of `On` it says `Do`. But it really depends on which events of which classes.

Comment: I corrected as you putted. The second option is what I want. I use FireDAC or Zeos depending on Delphi's version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To intercept the `OnBeforeScroll` event without interfering with the user's `OnBeforeScroll` event handler, you need to override each component's virtual `DoBeforeScroll()` method.  However, a *class helper* cannot override any virtual methods of the class it is helping.  So, you will have to instead either:

1. write new classes that are derived from each base component class you want to intercept (`type TMyCustomQuery = class(TCustomQuery)`, etc), and then the user must use those new component classes in their code instead of the originals.
2. (XE and later only) use Delphi's [`TVirtualMethodInterceptor`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/en/TVirtualMethodInterceptor_(Delphi)) class to hook the virtual `DoBeforeScroll()` method of specific component object instances (not the classes themselves) without having to write any derived classes.

The alternative is to write a class, possibly a Generic class, that the user has to instantiate for each component object instance, and the class can then subclass its associated component (possibly with RTTI) to capture and replace the user's `OnBeforeScroll` event handler with its own, and then its event handler can call the user's event handler when needed.

Comment: I didn't say anything about globals.

Comment: @EASI I'm assuming you're referring to having to write an inherited class to use in replacement of a standard one?